# Showing all followers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to show up all followers that I have?
I have made following possible, but I don't know how to show users that are following. Also I don't know how will I show posts from all the people "I'm following".

```
#/app/controllers/followers_controller.rb
class FollowersController < ApplicationController
def index
    @user = current_user
    @followers = Follower.where(following_id: params[:user_id])
end
def create
    if current_user
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @follower = Follower.new(follower_params)
        @follower.user_id = current_user.id
        @follower.following_id = @user.id
        if @user != current_user
            @follower.save
        end
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end

def follower_params
    params.require(:follower).permit(:user_id, :following_id)
end
end

#/app/views/followers/index.html.erb
<% @followers.each do |f| %>
 <b><%= f.user_id %></b>
 <br/>
<% end %>


#/app/models/follower.rb
class Follower < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_uniqueness_of :following_id, scope: :user_id
 belongs_to :user
end

#/app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :password
 before_save :encrypt_password
 before_save { self.username = username.downcase }
 before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
 validates_confirmation_of :password
 validates_presence_of :password, on: :create, length: { minimum: 8 }
 validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { maximum: 255 }
 validates :username, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 30 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
 validates :bio, length: { maximum: 140 }
 has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :followers, dependent: :destroy
 has_attached_file :avatar,
                styles: {
                  thumb: '75x75#',
                  small: '150x150#'
                }
 validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
 has_attached_file :banner,
                styles: {
                  thumb: '75x75>',
                  small: '150x150>'
                }
 validates_attachment_content_type :banner, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
 def self.authenticate(username, password)
 user = find_by_username(username)
 if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
  user
 end
end

def encrypt_password
 if password.present?
  self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
end
end
end
```

Comment: Can you show your User Model and your Follower Model?

Comment: ? I can't see anything. Also, do you want to show all the followers(every single one of them)? Or you want to show all followers that are following a particular user?

Comment: Sorry I had to format it :D
I want to show followers that are following current user. I can get the data out of the database with @followers = Follower.where(following_id: params[:user_id]), but I don't know how to fetch users with that data I have

Answer (score 1):

So, there is a little adjustment to be made to your model's setup.

Since a follower is also a user, It means that your `Follower`(which I will rename to `Following` should be a join table.)

```
class Following < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leader, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
end
```

and your user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings, foreign_key: :follower_id,
                           dependent: :destroy
  has_many :leaders, through: :followings
  has_many :reverse_followings, foreign_key: :leader_id,
                                class_name: 'Following',
                                dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_followings
end
```

Note that you will have to facilitate this by changing your migration to include the required columns.

Then you should be able to call `user.followers`

and run migrations.
Hope this helps?

Comment: Can you explain how do you get :follower if you renamed 'Follower' to 'Following'?

Comment: try: `rails g model Following leader_id:integer follower_id:integer`

Comment: Could not find the association :reverse_followings in model User :/